# The "Fisherman" idea for indirectly determining the validity of the canonical chain?

Tags: sharding, cross-chain, cross-shard-transaction, data-validity

The following article explains the problem of validating a block in a cross-shard transaction in a **sharded** chain, along with existing solutions.

One of the mentioned solutions is the "**Fisherman**" idea in which:

> "Whenever a block header is communicated between chains for any
>   purpose (such as cross-linking to the beacon chain, or a cross-shard
>   transaction), there’s a period of time during which any honest
>   validator can provide a proof that the block is invalid."

**Link to the article:** https://medium.com/nearprotocol/unsolved-problems-in-blockchain-sharding-2327d6517f43

I could not find the **seminal** paper / article that has **proposed** the Fisherman idea **for the first time**.

- Where is the article that has proposed the Fisherman idea for the first time?

Any help is appreciated.